# Multiply list with vector R

Tags: r, vector, lapply

So I have a set of data frames collected in a list. I want to multiply a set of columns in these data frames with a vector. The following seems to work fine if I want to e.g., add one to each column:

```
my_list <- list(data.frame(c(1,2), c(3,4)), data.frame(c(5,6), c(7,8)))


my_new_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x) {

  # I Do not want to do anything to the first column
  x[, -1] <- x[, -1] * 2
  return(x)
}
)
```

However, instead of mulyiplying 2, I want to multiply different values from a vector of the same length as `my_list`, e.g., multiply by 2 for the first object in `my_list` and multiply by 100 for the second object. Simply replacing 2 with `c(2, 100)` will do the multiplication rowwise for each df and therefore does not yield the desired result. (It works because each df has same amount of rows as the vector). Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
vec <- c(2, 100)
my_new_list <- Map(`*`, my_list, vec)
```

Equivalent in `purrr` is `map2`.

```
my_new_list <- purrr::map2(my_list, vec, `*`)
```

---

Using `lapply`, we can iterate over the index :

```
lapply(seq_along(vec), function(x) my_list[[x]] * vec[x])
purrr::map(seq_along(vec), ~my_list[[.x]] * vec[.x])
```

---

To keep first column as it is.

```
Map(function(x, y) {x[-1] <- x[-1] * y;x}, my_list, vec)
```